# TYPO3 : Automated TCA Generation for dynamic Domain-Model-Properties

Tags: configuration, typo3, domain-model

I have built some Domain-Model-Objects, that represent DataRecords coming from an XML-Interface. To keep those Objects versatile, they are being set up using dynamic properties during __construct, using Records of an own Object-Property-Model => This allows me to add Properties via simple Backend-Module.
My problem is, that I would like to dynamically generate TCA settings (columns etc) for those properties. I have the necessary info like datatype for those columns available - Is it possible to set up functions in TCA files, that read data via DB-Connection-Pool or Records coming from a Repository to extend column data based on that dynamic data?
Best regards, Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work with [TCA overrides](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/ExtendingTca/StoringChanges/Index.html#storing-in-the-overrides-folder) or the `tcaIsBeingBuilt` signal emitted by `ExtensionManagementUtility`.

You can also have a look at the extension [autoloader](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/autoloader/) which does something similar with its Smart Objects.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with that new signal. Wasn`t aware of that before.

Comment: Do you think it would be bad practice to directly modify $GLOBALS['TCA'] directly in the related controller before calling PersistenceManager`s persistAll() !?

Comment: This depends on your own workflow. TYPO3 doesn't care what you do in your TCA overrides or in a slot. Basically you only need to think about whether you want to use this in other locations or ways too.

Answer (score 0):

Just some additional info for those who may run into the same question :

You can make use of any repo/controller/etc. in a php-file in TCA/Overrides by instantiating the TYPO3-objectManager, which you can use to manually get your desired classes with full initialization.
As soon as you have your desired data (Object-Proberties/Tabledata, whatever) you can simply override $GLOBALS['TCA'][''] directly.
This way, you can build up dynamic models with modifyable properties.
I will now have to check, how I could possibly care about automatic modification of the db-table and extension sql-file for the table where persistent records of those dynamic models are being kept.